# Checking if some one has already voted

Tags: php, mysql

Im using a simple ajax script to allow users to vote against multiple posts on a page. However I dont want the same user to vote against the same post more than once, to try and avoid this I log the users, ID, Username and the ID of the post to which they have voted in a database.

Like so:

```
$updatevoters = "INSERT INTO voters VALUES('$userid', '$id', '$username')";
```

What I now need to do is before submitting the vote to the database is make sure that the user hasnt already done so.

How can I query the database, Im thinking of using `COUNT` or something similar, to check if there are any matches?

Im not sure how to take all 3 variables `$userid, $id and $username` and compare against the `voters` table.

Essentially I'd like to be able to build an IF:

```
If ($count = 0) {
  ADD THE VOTE TO TABLE
} else {
  //DIE
}
```

Any help appreciate....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM voters WHERE userid='$userid' AND id='$id' AND username='$username'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    // there ARE rows so user has already voted
}
else{
    // no rows... user hasn't voted yet
}
```

no need for count... if they're in the database then they've voted. :)

Comment: Make sure you have a index across the three columns to improve this lookup.

Comment: No, *use* COUNT - you're sending back all the column data in the table, only to completely ignore it for sake of what amounts to COUNT.

Comment: You don't have to select all of it - send back just the ID if you want. Even if you count you have to send back something.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the voting records for the specific user ID. If the count is zero, allow them to vote.

And please tell me that `$username` is escaped or sanitized somewhere before the line `"INSERT INTO voters VALUES('$userid', '$id', '$username')";`

Comment: I would assume (read "hope") that username was escaped before the user was signed up... and the string that is being used is just this recycled field, rather than a user input.

Comment: Using Oauth so Username comes from the Oauth session, its not input by the user via the site.